why Electron with electron builder in Laravel not automatically startup self localhost
i configure electron with electron builder , like create main.cjs and config package.json , and then run npm run electron-build , created a stepup.exe and then installed like install (headman-system Setup 1.0.0.exe ) , after instaled worked , but when computer shutdown or send that ( headman-system Setup 1.0.0.exe ) to install in another computer , not worked to show content of project means not start localhost , when back to project run npm run electron or npm run start , after run see that installed (headman-system Setup 1.0.0.exe )and shortcut of app is lunched good can see content of project , i don't now why not automatically start localhost when access to shortcut of app , why always remain on loding.html
i try to fix but i cant always not automatically start localhost :
code :
main.cjs
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const path = require("path");
const { exec } = require("child_process");
const AutoLaunch = require("auto-launch");

const PORT = 50505; // Unique port for localhost

let phpServer;

function createWindow() {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        icon: path.join(app.getAppPath(), "public/assets/img/1.png"),
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
        },
    });

    win.setMenuBarVisibility(false);
    win.loadFile("loading.html");

    const checkServer = () => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:${PORT}`)
            .then(() => {
                win.loadURL(`http://localhost:${PORT}`); // Load the main content once the server is ready
            })
            .catch(() => {
                setTimeout(checkServer, 1000); // Retry after 1 second if the server is not ready
            });
    };

    checkServer(); // Start checking the server status
}

function startServices() {
    const phpPath = path.join(app.getAppPath(), "php", "php.exe");
    const publicPath = path.join(app.getAppPath(), "public");

    console.log(`PHP Path: ${phpPath}`);
    console.log(`Public Path: ${publicPath}`);

    phpServer = exec(
        `${phpPath} -S localhost:${PORT} -t ${publicPath}`,
        (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(`Exec error: ${error}`);
                return;
            }
            console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
            console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        }
    );

    phpServer.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
        console.log(`PHP Server: ${data}`);
    });

    phpServer.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
        console.error(`PHP Server Error: ${data}`);
    });

    phpServer.on("close", (code) => {
        console.log(`PHP Server exited with code ${code}`);
    });
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    startServices();
    createWindow();

    // Setup auto-launch
    const autoLauncher = new AutoLaunch({
        name: "Headman",
        path: app.getPath("exe"),
    });

    autoLauncher.isEnabled().then((isEnabled) => {
        if (!isEnabled) autoLauncher.enable();
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    });

    app.on("activate", () => {
        if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
            createWindow();
        }
    });
});



app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
    if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
        if (phpServer) phpServer.kill();
        app.quit();
    }
});

packge,json
{
    "private": true,
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build",
        "electron": "electron .",
        "electron-build": "electron-builder"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
        "axios": "^1.6.4",
        "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
        "electron": "^31.2.1",
        "electron-builder": "^24.13.3",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^1.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.56.1",
        "vite": "^5.0.0"
    },
    "name": "headman-system",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "<p align=\"center\"><a href=\"https://laravel.com\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laravel/art/master/logo-lockup/5%20SVG/2%20CMYK/1%20Full%20Color/laravel-logolockup-cmyk-red.svg\" width=\"400\" alt=\"Laravel Logo\"></a></p>",
    "main": "electron/main.cjs",
    "build": {
        "appId": "com.headman.id",
        "directories": {
            "output": "dist"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/**/*",
            "bootstrap/**/*",
            "config/**/*",
            "database/**/*",
            "electron/**/*",
            "node_modules/**/*",
            "php/**/*",
            "public/**/*",
            "resources/**/*",
            "routes/**/*",
            "storage/**/*",
            "vendor/**/*",
            ".editorconfig",
            ".env",
            "artisan",
            "composer.json",
            "composer.lock",
            "loading.html",
            "package-lock.json",
            "package.json",
            "phpunit.xml",
            "vite.config.js"
      
        ],
        "win": {
            "icon": "public\\assets\\img\\icon.ico"
        },
        "nsis": {
            "oneClick": false,
            "perMachine": false,
            "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
            "createDesktopShortcut": true,
            "createStartMenuShortcut": true,
            "shortcutName": "Headman"
        },
        "extraResources": [
            {
                "from": "electron",
                "to": "app",
                "filter": [
                    "**/*"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "anymatch": "^3.1.3",
        "asynckit": "^0.4.0",
        "auto-launch": "^5.0.6",
        "binary-extensions": "^2.3.0",
        "braces": "^3.0.3",
        "chokidar": "^3.6.0",
        "combined-stream": "^1.0.8",
        "delayed-stream": "^1.0.0",
        "esbuild": "^0.21.5",
        "fill-range": "^7.1.1",
        "follow-redirects": "^1.15.6",
        "form-data": "^4.0.0",
        "glob-parent": "^5.1.2",
        "immutable": "^4.3.6",
        "is-binary-path": "^2.1.0",
        "is-extglob": "^2.1.1",
        "is-glob": "^4.0.3",
        "is-number": "^7.0.0",
        "mime-db": "^1.52.0",
        "mime-types": "^2.1.35",
        "nanoid": "^3.3.7",
        "normalize-path": "^3.0.0",
        "picocolors": "^1.0.1",
        "picomatch": "^2.3.1",
        "postcss": "^8.4.39",
        "proxy-from-env": "^1.1.0",
        "readdirp": "^3.6.0",
        "rollup": "^4.18.1",
        "source-map-js": "^1.2.0",
        "to-regex-range": "^5.0.1",
        "vite-plugin-full-reload": "^1.2.0"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "suli core team",
    "license": "ISC"
}



Laravel/PHP is not a native part of Electron and so it does not know about getting it up and running. Have a look at NativePHP which helps to integrate them

Just a suggestion. When asking a question make your question more clear. Writing in dot points and paragraphs can help this
